# How to get route parameter using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am hitting a REST endpoint at

```
www.example.com/resource/id
```

What is the best way for me to extract id from an angular module controller?
I have looked into using $routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when('/resource/:id', {}).otherwise(...)
```

This will only work if I set

```
$locationProvider.html5mode(true)
```

If it is not set to true, it always ends up in the otherwise clause when I hit www.example.com/resource/8

How can I get this to work even if I don't set $locationProvider.html5mode to true?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `$route.current.params`, I use angular-ui's ui-router [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), in which case you would use $stateParams.

Answer (score 0):

use `www.example.com#/resource/8` instead `www.example.com/resource/8`

Answer (score 0):

just replace following  code:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/resource/:id', {}).otherwise(...)
```

with the:

```
 $routeProvider.when('resource/:id', {}).otherwise(...)
```

`/resource/:id` ths take absolute url pattern. and `resource/:id` take relative url pattern.

so i think this will help you without setting of html mode true.